# page jumping to the middle when clicking on a field SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a multiline field with lots of data sometimes it has 17 pages long.

When you click on this field it will jump to the middle of the field. I want it to stay on the top and if you need you can scroll down,

How will I do this ?

Comment: You may be able to cheat the page post-back by using a hidden anchor tag?

Comment: Anchor tag ? how do i do that ?

Comment: an HTML anchor tag is how you create links using HTML <a hef="?">target page area</a>

Comment: Mine jumps to the end if it's plain text and I tab into it. Using rich text or enhanced rich text, the cursor stays at the top.

Comment: can you explain a bit more please Erin. @CollaborationGuy i sort of have to have a post back as its a connected webpart