# Jump to page withing a document via sharepoint link

Tags: search, office-365

This question is similar [page jumping to the middle when clicking on a field SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186857/page-jumping-to-the-middle-when-clicking-on-a-field-sharepoint)

I want to jump to a spcific page (say page 10) of document (say abc.docx) hosted on office 365  (or on prem sharepoint).

There are a lot of links in internet which tell that we can create anchor in our document and then give #anchor name in url to navigate to page.

However the documents hosted by sharepoint are not editable and are huge in number. So **need a URL which directly points to specific page within document hosted by SharePoint.**